# How to use same menu bar with multiple form in c# window application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am create a window application with multiple forms ,but my problem is cannot fix the menu bar .i need menu bar is fixed and bottom of the window only changed.

Comment: Set main form ismdicontainer property to true  and add menustrip control

Comment: thank you,plz give any reference link

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw8zc76(v=vs.110).aspx; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984329(v=vs.71).aspx;

Comment: I'd just fill the main area of the form with a Panel on which you load other custom screens you make as user controls instead of separate forms.